# How to upload/attach images with discord API using axios?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, axios, discord

How can I upload/attach images when sending a message to a channel using Discord API & Axios?

They explain it here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files

but the way they explained it doesn't make any sense especially when it comes to making that request with axios.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google about Axios & FormData

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.